# Set Eureka DateTimeRow with specific time

Tags: ios, swift3, eureka-forms

I am trying to setup the starting time of DateTimeRow() so that whenever I clicked on date the DateTime picker time will spin to 7:30 AM.

The following code is only changing the display text while not spinning the date picker:

```
row = DateTimeRow() {
    $0.minuteInterval = 30
}.onCellSelection({(cell,row) in
    if row.baseCell.detailTextLabel?.text == nil {

    // Setup the start date
    var currentDate = NSDate() as Date
    currentDate = currentDate.setHoursMinutes(hour: 7, minute: 30)
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current

    // This will show the current day date with time of 7:30 AM
    row.baseCell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate)
}
```

Is there a way to access the picker directly and calling setDate like:

```
timePicker.setDate([My Date here], animated: true)
```

[image: Display Text label is update while the date picker is not]

Thanks you

Comment: Yes, you call this function and then when the picker is displayed, it will scroll to the date that you have set, with animation or not.

Comment: Thank you, but as you can see in the attached image the date picker is not scrolled while the display text is changed

Comment: Did you call this function before showing the datepicker view?

Comment: No, after showing the datepicker and onCellSelection only

Comment: uhmm, it should work even you call before or after. Can you show your code?

Comment: Actually my code is a part of a complicated project and I am generating the form using JSON source. Every thing are working except this functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been working on your question, first of all you are setting up your cell on `onCellSelection` callback I think that you need setup your date value on cell creation something like this

```
 <<< DateTimeRow() {
            var currentDate = Date()
            currentDate = currentDate.setHoursMinutes(hour: 7, minute: 30)
            $0.value = currentDate
            }
```

or you need to use the `cellSetup` callback, and if you want show a dateTime different then you need to implement the `onCellSelection` callback

```
<<< DateTimeRow().cellSetup({ (dateCell, dateTimeRow) in
                        // Setup the start date
                        let currentDate = Date()
                        currentDate = currentDate.setHoursMinutes(hour: 7, minute: 30)
                        dateTimeRow.dateFormatter?.dateStyle = .short
                        dateTimeRow.dateFormatter?.timeStyle = .short
                        //dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
                        dateCell.row.value = currentDate
            }).onCellSelection({ (cell, row) in
                //If you want to show different date 
                let currentDate = NSDate() as Date
                currentDate.setHoursMinutes(hour: 9, minute: 30)    
                cell.datePicker.date = currentDate
            })
```

I hope this helps you, best regards